# rsync error after a while: "rsync service is no running"

Tags: rsync, migration, network-attached-storage

I am migrating data from an old WD NAS to a Synology NAS via rsync. For some reason, my rsync processes are killed after a while, with the error message:

```
rsync error: rsync service is no running (code 43) at io.c(687) [receiver=3.0.9]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(687) [generator=3.0.9]
```

I am pulling that data to the new Synology NAS through the LAN, i.e. I am running the rsync process on the Synology. According to [this post](https://sejh.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/synology-network-backup-failing-with-rsync-error/) this may be related to `rsyncd`(not running), but it seems strange, considering not only that it *occasionally* works (for sometimes up to a few hours). I get no stability, however. Any ideas on what to do?

Additional data:

- The folders I am migrating are around 500 GB to 1500 GB in total size per rsync process, where the file sizes vary from the very small up to 4-5 GB max.

Comment: I have same issue while using Synology to backup data from Ubuntu 16 server.